# Windows Phone app how to test if bluetooth connection is working in the simulator

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How can i test if my application bluetooth connection is working properly. I cant test it on phone because i dont have 2 windows phones. Also if 2 users connect do they share the same screen i.e if one of them enters some info in a textbox can i make it so that the other one is unable to see while the user that wrote text in the tb can clearly read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Bluetooth Manager in NuGet.
[Download Bluetooth Manager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BluetoothManager/)

To practice I've packaged up my Bluetooth Manager library. This is a little wrapper class that makes it really easy to use Bluetooth on Windows 10 applications. I've not tried it on Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi (but I've tried it on lots of other systems and it works fine). You can find out a bit more about it here.  I use it so that I can print message on my little home made Bluetooth printer, but you can use it anywhere you want to talk over a Bluetooth serial connection.

Oh, and in case you are wondering why it is version 1.0.1 and not version 1.0.0 I found an interesting quirk in nuget. If your library class doesn't have a public constructor the package will fail to work because Visual Studio will complain that the class is "Inaccessible due to its protection level.". That's what happens when you try to use version 1.0.0